# Nhibernate invalid cast

Tags: nhibernate, casting, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to create a DTO object for a HQL query I am running, however, when executing my HQL query from my repository it is producing a NH cast error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.SqlNode' to type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.FromReferenceNode'.
```

Has anyone come across this before?

My DTO mapping and class are below:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// TODO: Update summary.
    /// </summary>
    public class TaskListItemMapping : ClassMap<TaskListItem>
    {
        public TaskListItemMapping()
        {
            ImportType<TaskListItem>();
            Id(x => x.TaskCode).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        }
    }




 /// <summary>
    /// A class representing a task list data query result
    /// </summary>
    public class TaskListItem
    {
        public virtual int Code { get; set; }

        public virtual String Client { get; set; }

        public virtual string Matter { get; set; }

        public virtual DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

        public virtual bool Notepad { get; set; }

        public virtual bool Flag { get; set; }

        public virtual string Client { get; set; }

        public virtual string Issue { get; set; }

        public virtual string Grade { get; set; }

        public virtual String TaskInitials { get; set; }

        public virtual string Description { get; set; }

        public TaskListItem()
        {

        }
    }
```

Any thoughts appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was causing this - it was a mis-match on data in the constructor